# Google Drive API with GoogleSignInAccount fails

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin, google-drive-android-api, googlesigninaccount

I am trying to use Google Drive Api on android, I managed to sign in using GoogleSignIn and get a GoogleSignInAccount, but then when I try to call Drive api such as mDriveResourceClient.getRootFolder().continueWithTask(continuation) , I get an error in logcat : "Authorization failed: Unsupported scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".
And after a long time ( more than 30 seconds ) 'OnFailureListener' is called with unknown error.

( I Enabled Drive api in the api developer console )

Anyone familiar with this issue ?

Comment: Please show full relevant code.

Comment: I am facing same issue with the android-demos sample ( https://github.com/googledrive/android-demos )